# sending multidimensional array with curl in json format

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, curl

I am trying to post data using curl to a api, it has to be in JSON.
Now I have an multidimensional array that i need to pass along with the post. But i keep getting the same error all over, and i can not figure out why.

I've tried every possible way I could imagine.

This is the example that i need to send to the API:

```
POST /orders/ HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic aHVudGVyMjo=
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "currency": "EUR",
    "amount": 99,
    "return_url": "http://www.example.com/",
    "transactions": [
      {
       "payment_method": "ideal",
       "payment_method_details": {
           "issuer_id": "INGBNL2A"
        }
      }
     ]
}
```

So my array I made like this:

```
$post_fields = array();
$post_fields["currency"] = "EUR";
$post_fields["amount"] = 99;
$post_fields["return_url"] = "http://website_url.nl/return_page/";
$post_fields["transactions"]["payment_method"] = "ideal";
$post_fields["transactions"]["payment_method_details"]["issuer_id"] = "INGBNL2A";
```

Then the follinw i do is converting the array to a JSON string by this code:

```
$data_string = json_encode($post_fields);
```

So far is everything OK, but then i am going to post the data to the API by using the following code:

```
$url = "https://api.kassacompleet.nl/v1/orders/";

$curl_header = array();
$curl_header[] = "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$auth_code:");
$curl_header[] = "Content-type: application/json";

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 180);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
```

And this always results in an error that looks as the following:

```
{ "error": { "status": 400, "type": "", "value": "{u'payment_method': u'ideal', u'payment_method_details': {u'issuer_id': u'INGBNL2A'}} is not of type u'array'" } }
```

Could someone tell me where it comes from and what I am doing wrong?
Is it the format of the array or what is it?

Comment: Typically you need to supply `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` a http query string or a php array that it will turn into a http query string.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Are you trying to say that I do not need to send that as JSON ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From checking the [API documentaion](http://www.wp-pay.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/API-Documentation-Kassa-Compleet.pdf)
 It looks like *transactions* should be an array.

```js
$post_fields = array();
$post_fields["currency"] = "EUR";
$post_fields["amount"] = 99;
$post_fields["return_url"] = "http://website_url.nl/return_page/";
$post_fields["transactions"][0]["payment_method"] = "ideal";
$post_fields["transactions"][1]["payment_method_details"]["issuer_id"] = "INGBNL2A";

echo  '<pre>'.json_encode($post_fields).'</pre>';

/* outputs...
{
 "currency":"EUR",
 "amount":99,
 "return_url":"http:\/\/website_url.nl\/return_page\/",
 "transactions":[
 {
 "payment_method":"ideal",
 "payment_method_details":{
    "issuer_id":"INGBNL2A"
    }
  }
  ]
}
*/
```

Comment: Thank you this is working indeed, I got already an other answer now. But this is resulting the following: NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that param "issuer_id" should be an array, in that case try

...
$post_fields["transactions"]["payment_method_details"]["issuer_id"] = array("INGBNL2A");
...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunatly that doesn't work. I get the following response: { "error": { "status": 400, "type": "", "value": "{u'payment_method': u'ideal', u'payment_method_details': {u'issuer_id': [u'INGBNL2A']}} is not of type u'array'" } }

Comment: If you read the error, it is saying the entire json string being passed is not an array. As in `{u'payment_method': u'ideal', u'payment_method_details': {u'issuer_id': u'INGBNL2A'}} is not of type u'array'`.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Oke, I understand that, but how am I able to convert it to an array then ? Cause I tought it was already an array because it was an array before the JSON convert

Comment: $post_fields = array($post_fields); ?